# Java: Read integers from an existing text file and output to another file

Tags: java

**BAR CHART**

Write a Java program that reads today's sales figures (integers) for five stores from an existing text file called sales.txt and output to a new file called storeReport.txt

The program should display a bar chart comparing each store's sales.  Create each bar in the bar chart by displaying a row of asterisks.  Each asterisk should represent $100 of sales.

**Below are the integers to be read from sales.txt:**

```
1000
1200
1800
800
1900
```

**The output file (storeReport.txt) should look like this:**

```
Store 1: **********
Store 2: ************
Store 3: ******************
Store 4: ********
Store 5: *******************
```

Keep in mind, I'm only in Chapter 5: Intro to Loops and Files, of Intro to Java.  The answer must be *very simplistic*. We haven't gotten to the following in my text yet, so please refrain from using them:  int[ ],  bufferedWriter, fstream, .length,  out.print .....etc, etc

Thus, I must use the simplest of code such as:

```
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner (file)
File inputFile = new File (sales.text)
PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter (storeReport.txt)
```

We may use for loops, while loops, and nested loops.

Below is the code that I've written thus far.  I'm getting compile errors.  Please help!!  Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.io.*;

public class BarChart
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException

   {   

        int store1,store2,store3,store4,store5;
        int bar1,bar2,bar3,bar4,bar5;

        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(System.in); 

        File inputFile = new File("sales.txt");


        File outputFile = new File("storeReport.txt");  

        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("storeReport.txt");


        outputFile.println("SALES BAR CHART\n");            

        bar1 = store1/100;
        outputFile.println("store 1 : ");
        for(int i = 1; i <= bar1; i++)
            outputFile.println("*");

        bar2 = store2/100;
        outputFile.println("\nStore 2 : ");
        for(int i = 1; i <= bar2; i++)
            outputFile.println("*");

        bar3 = store3/100;
        outputFile.println("\nStore 3 : ");
        for(int i = 1; i <= bar3; i++)
            outputFile.println("*");

        bar4 = store4/100;
        outputFile.println("\nStore 4 : ");
        for(int i = 1; i <= bar4; i++)
            outputFile.println("*");

        bar5 = store5/100;
        outputFile.println("\nStore 5 : ");
        for(int i = 1; i <= bar5; i++)
            outputFile.println("*");

        inputFile.close();

        outputFile.close();     

        System.out.println("Data written to the storeReport.txt");
        System.exit(0);

    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend editing your question to include the compilation error.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you've got 2 variables named inputFile:

```
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(System.in);           
File inputFile = new File("sales.txt");
```

Try renaming the first one to inputScanner.
Same deal for outputFile.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your code would be able to successfully produce the desired output to `storeReport.txt` - *if* `store1`, `store2` etc. had contained the numbers from `sales.txt`, which they don't. You have not told Java to read the numbers from the file and into the variables; they won't automatically get populated with data from the file. The compile error you're getting is probably related to using variables that haven't been initialized (i.e., they don't contain any data yet). Reread the part of your book that covers file *input* to find out how you can load data from a file into your variables. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would consider a method like this

```
static void printBar(int sales) {
    int bar = sales / 100;
    for(int i = 0; i < bar; i++) outFile.print("*");
    outFile.println(""); // flush and finish line
}
```

You can employ this effectively for each of your inputs. You would have to set up your outFile variable as a static class variable, or pass it in as a parameter to `printBar()`.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. You cannot have two local variables in the same scope with the same name.  Particularly look at your declarations of `inputFile`.
2. You need to review the purpose of the `Scanner` and `File` classes.  Read the javadocs, and look at the methods and constructors they declare.
3. The statement `bar1 = store1/100;` in the current version of the code will (once you've fixed other errors) give you a compilation error saying that `store1` has not been initialized.  Local variables must be initialized before you use them.
4. Creating a `Scanner` object doesn't actually read anything.  You have to call methods on the object to make it do something.